# Not booting except in recovery mode

Tags: boot, nvidia, fstab, recovery-mode

I don't even understand the problem.

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sda5 during installation   
UUID=27e7d1a1-a5c3-4eee-a3d0-a326727bf5c3 /               ext4   
errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot/efi was on /dev/sda1 during installation 
UUID=36AA-CB51      vfat     umask=0077      0       0
swapfile                       none            swap    sw      0       0
```

Comment: I think it may be because of my graphic card or something.

Comment: Did you modify your fstab file recently?

Comment: No, at least I don't think so. Everything happened when I updated my drivers via "Additional Drivers".

Comment: When you're in recovery mode, type in your root password, then try to edit fstab, see if something has changed there

Comment: Okay, I'll try to make a picture to it.

Comment: There it is, now in the main question

Answer (score 1):

Okay, problem solved.

It was as I feared a problem with my graphic card.

I uninstalled all related to nvidia with purge and --remove and then reinstalled it.

Now it boots without any trouble.